How to send a parameter directly to LLM in langchain
Currently I can send grammar in HuggingfaceEndpoint as parameters in the constructor:
class QuestionValidator(BaseModel):
    label: str


llm_base = HuggingFaceEndpoint(
    endpoint_url=ENDPOINT_URL,
    max_new_tokens=1024,
    seed=60,
    model_kwargs={"grammar": {"type": "json", "value": QuestionValidator.schema()}}
)

llm_with_grammar = prompt | llm_base | JsonOutputParser()
res = llm_with_grammar.invoke(
    {"question": "tell me a joke?", "table_schemas": schema_info}
)
print(res)

However, I want to send grammar dynamically? For example, instead of the constructor (HuggingFaceEndpoint), can I use invoke to pass a specific grammar?
I also found the with_config in langchain is relevant, but don't know how to use it:
https://python.langchain.com/v0.1/docs/expression_language/primitives/configure/
Something like the following:
llm_base = HuggingFaceEndpoint(
    endpoint_url=ENDPOINT_URL,
    max_new_tokens=1024,
    seed=60,
)

grammar1 = {"grammar": {"type": "json", "value": QuestionValidator.schema()}}
grammar2 = {"grammar": {"type": "json", "value": AnswerValidator.schema()}}

llm_with_grammar1 = prompt_tmplate_1 | llm_base.with_config(grammar1) | StrOutputParser()
llm_with_grammar2 = prompt_tmplate_2 | llm_base.with_config(grammar2) | StrOutputParser()


After searching langchain, I didn't find something relevant to fix the above. I found an alternative using ChatModel:
chat_model = ChatHuggingFace(llm=llm_base)
grammar1 = {"type": "json", "value": QuestionValidator.schema()}

res = chat_model.invoke([
    ("system", system_prompt.format(table_schemas=schema_info)),
    ("user", "How many employees do we have in total?")
],
    response_format=grammar1
)

I also found another alternative:
def llm_with_grammar(inputs, llm, grammar):
    return llm.invoke(inputs, response_format=grammar)

chain = prompt | functools.partial(llm_with_grammar, llm=chat_model, grammar=grammar1) | JsonOutputParser()

